# "Cannot Open Source File error" moving from VS 2013 to 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include

I have a working C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 that I've opened in Visual Studio 2015. In VS 2015, On these lines:

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

I get a *Cannot Open Source File error*

Looking in the project External Dependencies, these 2 files are not listed there.

[Looking at the breaking changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx)
I tried adding  legacy_stdio_definitions.lib. to the linker, but this had no effect.

What can I do?

Comment: What does a source file have to do with a library?  If your code didn't compile successfully, changing linker settings isn't going to help.

Comment: I guess I knew that, but it mentions <conio.h> so I had to try,